# android textview text direction now responding to changes

Tags: android, xml, styles

I am trying to do the right to left text direction, but I am getting unexpected result (not like the one when I do html css). Here is the code I have for that textview:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="96dp"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:text="@string/welcomeMsg"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:textDirection="rtl"
    android:textSize="@dimen/welcomeMsgSize" />
```

I believe I did everything there is to do. Maybe I forgot something or don't know it. I am pretty new to android. The picture shows the output of the above The problem here is the whitespace preceding the text inside the textview and post the text too. Thanks for your help in advance :)

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You should change Textview gravity from "Center" to "Right" or "Left" Depending on your need.
Gravity will set gravity to your text so change it. And also change the text alignment from center to right or left.

Comment: There is no right or left from what I am seeing in the docs.http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android:textAlignment

Comment: Just put this property in your TextView and everything will workout just fine it will automatically detect your text and change accordingly.

android:textDirection="anyRtl"

Answer (score 0):

android:textSize="@dimen/welcomeMsgSize"  there lies the culprit.. reduce the size you specified in that file there..!!

Comment: it is 26dp which is not big. Actually I may need it to be bigger later.

Comment: did you check if there was any padding variable set in the properties!

Comment: as you can see in the xml above, none are set